# How to create 3D plane from lines

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, helix-3d-toolkit

I'm using Helix Toolkit with WPF, and I want to take a bunch of lines and turn them into a surface.  To clarify, I have a group of 3-dimensional curves, and I want to get the curved blade that would result from all of these lines.  (The lines represent lines through the blade).

To an extent, I want to do the opposite of what [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596130/how-to-display-meshelement3d-as-wireframe) was asking about (use the lines as a wire frame to turn it into a model).

So far I have this XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="_3D_Geometry_Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:helix="clr-namespace:HelixToolkit.Wpf;assembly=HelixToolkit.Wpf"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:_3D_Geometry_Test">
    <Grid>
        <helix:HelixViewport3D x:Name="view1">
            <helix:DefaultLights/>               
            <helix:MeshGeometryVisual3D x:Name="bladesMeshGeo" />    
        </helix:HelixViewport3D>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the relevant part of the code-behind (I'm not including the contents of `GetSplines()` and `GetSpars()` since they consist entirely of me adding a lot of `Point3D` objects to each list):

```
using HelixToolkit.Wpf;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
namespace _3D_Geometry_Test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        const int NUM_SPLINES = 11;
        const int NUM_SPARS = 10;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<Point3D>[] splines = GetSplines();
            List<Point3D>[] spars = GetSpars();

            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SPLINES; i++)
            {
                bladesMeshGeo.Children.Add(new LinesVisual3D
                {
                    Points = new Point3DCollection(splines[i]),
                    Color = Colors.Red
                });
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SPARS; i++)
            {
                bladesMeshGeo.Children.Add(new LinesVisual3D
                {
                    Points = new Point3DCollection(spars[i]),
                    Color = Colors.Blue
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is this:

[image: curves]

But I want something like this:

[image: blades]

**Edit:** I'm not wedded to Helix Toolkit, so if anyone knows of another library that can accomplish this, I'd be grateful to hear of it!

Comment: Maybe the surface Demo can help you. Depending on how you generate the splines: https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/tree/master/Source/Examples/WPF/SurfaceDemo

Comment: @egse I did look at that, but I couldn't decipher how the actual surface gets drawn - I couldn't even figure out which class is responsible for the surface generation.

Comment: Oh, and the splines are currently 'generated' by a co-worker giving me several lists of 3D points.  I'm still waiting on the actual math that produced those points, so right now I'm trying to go from the list of 3D points to a 3D curve to a 3D surface, without knowing the mechanism that produces the 3D points (which could possibly be part of the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the best I've come up with involves making lots and lots and lots of little triangles connecting all of the points, like so (XAML stays the same):

```
using HelixToolkit.Wpf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;

namespace _3D_Geometry_Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        const int NUM_SPLINES = 11;
        const int NUM_SPARS = 10;
        static Vector3D xAxis = new Vector3D(1, 0, 0);

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the window.
        /// </summary>
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MakeBlades3();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Makes the blades.
        /// </summary>
        public void MakeBlades3()
        {
            var splines = GetSplines();
            var spars = GetSpars();

            MeshBuilder builder = new MeshBuilder(true, true);

            for (int i = 0; i < splines.Length; i++)
            {
                var currSpline = splines[i];
                if (i < splines.Length - 1)
                {
                    var nextSpline = splines[i + 1];
                    for (int j = 0; j < currSpline.Count; j++)
                    {
                        Point3D currPoint = currSpline[j];
                        Point3D pt1, pt2;
                        Find2NN(currPoint, nextSpline, out pt1, out pt2);
                        builder.AddTriangle(currPoint, pt1, pt2);

                        if (j > 0)
                        {
                            Point3D prevPoint = currSpline[j - 1];
                            Point3D pt3 = FindNN(currPoint, prevPoint, nextSpline);
                            builder.AddTriangle(currPoint, prevPoint, pt3);
                        }

                        if (j < currSpline.Count - 1)
                        {
                            Point3D nextPoint = currSpline[j + 1];
                            Point3D pt3 = FindNN(currPoint, nextPoint, nextSpline);
                            builder.AddTriangle(currPoint, nextPoint, pt3);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    var prevSpline = splines[i - 1];
                    for (int j = 0; j < currSpline.Count; j++)
                    {
                        Point3D currPoint = currSpline[j];
                        Point3D pt1, pt2;
                        Find2NN(currPoint, prevSpline, out pt1, out pt2);
                        builder.AddTriangle(currPoint, pt1, pt2);

                        if (j > 0)
                        {
                            Point3D prevPoint = currSpline[j - 1];
                            Point3D pt3 = FindNN(currPoint, prevPoint, prevSpline);
                            builder.AddTriangle(currPoint, prevPoint, pt3);
                        }
                        if (j < currSpline.Count - 1)
                        {
                            Point3D nextPoint = currSpline[j + 1];
                            Point3D pt3 = FindNN(currPoint, nextPoint, prevSpline);
                            builder.AddTriangle(currPoint, nextPoint, pt3);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            bladePlot.MeshGeometry = builder.ToMesh();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Finds the point in the input list of points that is closest to the two input points (Euclidean distance).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="origPoint1">The first point.</param>
        /// <param name="origPoint2">The second point.</param>
        /// <param name="listOfPoints">The list of points to find the nearest one in <note type="note">For the sake of speed, this should be a DISTINCT list (no duplicates).</note>.</param>
        /// <returns>The point in <paramref name="listOfPoints"/> that is closest to <paramref name="origPoint1"/> and <paramref name="origPoint2"/> (Euclidean distance).</returns>
        private Point3D FindNN(Point3D origPoint1, Point3D origPoint2, List<Point3D> listOfPoints)
        {
            Point3D result = listOfPoints[0];
            var dist = EuclidDist(origPoint1, result) + EuclidDist(origPoint2, result);
            for (int i = 1; i < listOfPoints.Count;i++)
            {
                var dist2 = EuclidDist(origPoint1, listOfPoints[i]) + EuclidDist(origPoint2, listOfPoints[i]);
                if (dist2 < dist)
                {
                    dist = dist2;
                    result = listOfPoints[i];
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Find the 2 nearest neighbors of the specified point (based on Euclidean distance).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="origPoint">The original point.</param>
        /// <param name="listOfPoints">A list of points to find the two nearest-neighbors from. <note type="note">For the sake of speed, this should be a DISTINCT list (no duplicates).</note></param>
        /// <param name="pt1">First nearest neighboring point (output).</param>
        /// <param name="pt2">Second nearest neighboring point (output).</param>
        private void Find2NN(Point3D origPoint, List<Point3D> listOfPoints, out Point3D pt1, out Point3D pt2)
        {
            pt1 = new Point3D();
            pt2 = new Point3D();

            List<Point3D> temp = new List<Point3D>(listOfPoints);

            pt1 = temp[0];
            var dist = EuclidDist(origPoint, pt1);
            for (int i = 1; i < temp.Count; i++)
            {
                var dist2 = EuclidDist(origPoint, temp[i]);
                if (dist2 < dist)
                {
                    dist = dist2;
                    pt1 = temp[i];
                }
            }
            temp.Remove(pt1);

            pt2 = temp[0];
            dist = EuclidDist(origPoint, pt2);
            for (int i = 1; i < temp.Count; i++)
            {
                var dist2 = EuclidDist(origPoint, temp[i]);
                if (dist2 < dist)
                {
                    dist = dist2;
                    pt2 = temp[i];
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Calculates the Euclidean distance between the two input points.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pt1">The first point.</param>
        /// <param name="pt2">The second point.</param>
        /// <returns>The Euclidean distance between <paramref name="pt1"/> and <paramref name="pt2"/>.</returns>
        private double EuclidDist(Point3D pt1, Point3D pt2)
        {
            double deltaX = pt1.X - pt2.X;
            double deltaY = pt1.Y - pt2.Y;
            double deltaZ = pt1.Z - pt2.Z;
            return Math.Sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY + deltaZ * deltaZ);
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting image looks like this:

[image]

This is definitely an improvement over the wireframe, but it's still not very smooth (not sure if that shows up on my posted image), and I'm convinced that there has to be a better solution, so I'll leave this as unanswered for now.  Just posting my (temporary) solution in case it helps anyone.

Comment: I'm marking this answer as the correct one because it is the solution that I will be using.